# Sync- Async- Multithreading on server application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm actually making a server application, which should recover a lot of data from the DB.
As it's a performance question to the main thread of the application, and the main thread needs to continue working while recovering data from DB, I need to know what are the best practices for such task. On one side I could use Threads, and as I understand, the main Thread assigns execution time to each sub-thread, is it possible to change/know the execution time assigned to each sub-thread? On the other side I have the posibility to use asynchronous Threads to do heavy work. So should I use sync or async Threads to do heavy work, and why?

Comment: The main thread **doesn't** assign execution time to the other threads. They run independently of each other. The operating system does all of the scheduling.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's handled by the OS, and that's why I was asking for the posibility. May BIOS programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asynchronous operation should be executed in another thread. That is, you're implementing multi-threaded code too.

There's no other way to parallelize work than *threading*, either using multi-tasking or actual parallelism using CPU cores.

This is why there's *no why* as you expect. Why? Because you need to execute tasks while main thread continues processing.